# ¿Cuándo se puede usar la frase "Fuenteovejuna, todos a una"?

Tags: expresiones

¿En qué contexto tiene sentido usarse la frase hecha "Fuenteovejuna, todos a una" de la obra de teatro "Fuenteovejuna", de Lope de Vega?

¿Cuándo se usa en la obra de teatro y en qué contextos similares hoy en día podría aplicarse?

Comment: No creo que haya escuchado que alguien lo use hoy en día, excepto haciendo clara referencia a la obra teatral.

Comment: @guifa creo que mis amigos manchegos la han usado alguna vez.

Comment: Yo también he escuchado *ha sido Fuenteovejuna* para referirse a cualquier cosa que tenga muchos causantes y no uno solo.

Comment: @Charlie pues tendrás amigos más cultos que los míos jajaja

Comment: Yo la he escuchado en contextos informales o television, desconociendo origen y significado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es curioso, porque en este caso me parece que estamos ante otro posible ejemplo de "tócala otra vez, Sam", que todo el mundo piensa que se dice en Casablanca pero la frase exacta no es así.

El texto tal y como salió de la pluma de Lope de Vega es:

> —¿Quién mató al Comendador?
>   —Fuenteovejuna, Señor.
>   —¿Quién es Fuenteovejuna?
>   —Todo el pueblo, a una.

En la obra original, el pueblo entero se pone de acuerdo para dar muerte a Hernán Pérez de Guzmán, Comendador Mayor de Calatrava, por los muchos agravios que pretendían haberles hecho. Y cuando se investiga al pueblo, por mucho que preguntan la respuesta que obtienen es siempre la citada arriba.

Buscando en el CORDE apariciones de "Fuenteovejuna" cerca de la palabra "todos", el único texto que me sale es el siguiente:

> *Y ahora os voy a decir una cosa. Callaros ya con Bakunin y Marx y toda esa gentuza. ¡U.H.P.! ¿Sabéis lo que quiere decir?: Unión de Hermanos Proletarios. Igual, igual que aquellos tíos de Fuenteovejuna: todos a una.*
>
> Arturo Barea, "La forja de un rebelde", 1951 (España).

A partir de ahí, en el CREA se encuentran hasta 5 casos del texto "Fuenteovejuna, todos a una", como el siguiente (que además demuestra cómo saltó el charco la expresión):

> *Además de ello, espanta, aterroriza, la actitud de irrespeto y desprecio por la vida. El hampa, la violencia terrorista, el imperio de los narcotraficantes. Como en Fuenteovejuna, todos a una quieren situar a los colombianos dentro de la categoría de los "gallináceos". Tengamos el valor civil de reconocer nuestro miedo; y lo que es más importante, la decisión de superarlo.*
>
> Jorge Iván Bonilla Vélez, "Violencia, medios y comunicación. Otras pistas en la investigación", 1995 (Colombia).

La idea básicamente es la misma que la de la frase "la unión hace la fuerza": la fuerza de un conjunto de individuos actuando al unísono suele ser mayor que la suma de sus fuerzas individuales.

Nótese que esto puede ser para bien o para mal, como por ejemplo pasa en el caso de los linchamientos mediáticos. Todo el pueblo se puede poner en contra de alguien o algo que ha podido ser acusado injustamente por algún medio de comunicación o que ha codigo inmerecida mala fama, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Puede hablarse de privilegio de una clase social, de una casta determinada, de unos magnates favorecidos por tales o cuales leyes o sistemas económicos, pero ¿en qué medida se beneficia una ciudad, que al servicio de un colectivo nacional, ha empezado por sacrificar su propia naturaleza y tranquilidad? Todo lo contrario de lo que ahora está de moda decir; que Madrid es un vampiro que chupa la sangre de las pobres provincias. Pero, de hecho, afirmaciones así encienden a las gentes, siempre dispuestas al "Fuenteovejuna, todos a una". Todos, pues, contra Madrid.*
>
> El País, 23/08/1977 : "Delenda est Madrid"

Comment: Interesante.  No encontré *delenda* en el DRAE.  (Pero sí en diccionarios de inglés, por ejemplo https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delenda%20est%20Carthago.) // A ver si entendí la expresión de la pregunta.  ¿Es otra manera de decir "todo el mundo"?

Comment: @aparente001 sí, es una frase latina. En el enlace que pones se ve "delenda est Carthago" (Cartago debe ser destruida), la cual se parodia en "delenda est Madrid".

Comment: Sí, capté eso, pero me pareció raro no encontrarlo en el DRAE.

Comment: @aparente001 cierto, no todos los [latinajos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Myl6hs5) aparecen en el DLE.